# How to make div with text and icon right

Tags: html, css

How to make div with center text and icon right like on this photo

[image]

Comment: Care to upload your HTML + CSS?

Comment: Make the image `position:absolute`, the wrapper `position:relative`, then set the image `right:0; top:0;`;

Comment: I have put a solution below. It only improves my typing skills :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you want.

```css
#red {
width:500px;
  height:100px;
  padding:20px;
  background-color:#f70c1e;
  color:white;
  line-height:100px;
  font-size:40px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  
}
img{
float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="red"> Yada yada .
  <img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/en_us/season-2012-su/open-graph/onenike_homepage_v1_opengraph_100x100.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div{
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
div img{
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Did you even try your answer before posting?

Comment: I know the image will come out of the div if it's large. But there's no CSS and HTML posted with the question, so I wasn't very clear about the answer he wanted.

Comment: In that case the question isn't worthy of an answer and ought to be closed. In fact the number of downvotes on the question indicates that, and has indeed been closed.

Comment: My apologies. I'm a newbie here and didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

text is in center picture on right

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img style="position: absolute; right:2.5%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two method to do you can use following are methods

### Inline method

```
div style="text-align: center;">
    <img style="position: absolute; right:2.5%;">
```

### EXTERNAL CSS method

```
div{
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
div img{
 float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just put it in a table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center;'>Text</td>
<td>Image</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And some css for the padding